# Sorting a Column by Default (on load) Using Dojo Dgrid

Tags: sorting, dojo, dgrid

When loading a dgrid from a dojo store, is there a way to specify a column to be sorted by default.

Say I have 2 columns, Name and Email, I want the name column sorted by default when the grid is first loaded. What I want is the equivalent of the user clicking on the 'Name' header (complete with the sort arrow indicating the sort direction).

Thanks,
John

Comment: It seems iv'e found the answer to my own question: `mytable.set('sort', 'name');`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
var mygrid = new OnDemandGrid({
    store : someStore,
    queryOptions: {
        sort: [{ attribute: "name" }]
    }
    // rest of your grid properties
}, "someNode");
```

Comment: of course the attribute would accept column name and direction. for example: [{attribute: 'id DESC'}]

Comment: For dGrid, that would be [{ attribute: "id", descending: true }]. If you omit descending : true, then it's assumed the sort is ascending. See http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/tutorials/grids_and_stores/

Comment: The only drawback of this is the arrow (up or down - depending on your descending value) isn't displayed. It's only displayed when the user actually clicks on the table header.

Comment: This appears to set the sort arrow for me so maybe the grid has been updated               grid.set('sort', 
              [{ attribute: this.defaultSortField, descending: this.defaultSortDirDesc }]
              )

Answer (score 0):

**dgrid 1.1.0** - set initial/default sort order

```
    var TrackableRest = declare([Rest, SimpleQuery, Trackable]);
    var store = new TrackableRest({target: apiUrl, useRangeHeaders: true, idProperty: 'id'});
    var grid = new (declare([OnDemandGrid, Selection, Editor]))({
        collection: store,
        sort: [{"property":"name", "descending": false}],
        className: "dgrid-autoheight",
        columns: {
            id: {
                label: core.id
            },
            category_text: {
                label: asset.category
            },
            name: {
                label: asset.model,
            },
```

Comment: The proper value for sort attribute is an array of objects:  [ { property: ''name", descending: true } ]